# String changes to null

Tags: java

Good morning, I'm using the following constructor code and for some reason the "position" variable sets to null every time a new object is created.

This is my class code

```
public class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int idNumber;
    private String department;
    private String position;

    public Employee(String nam, String depart, String posi, int id)
    {
       name = nam;
       department = depart;
       posi = position;
       idNumber = id;    
    }
}
```

And this is the line I'm using to create the object.

```
Employee sMeyers = new Employee("Susan Meyers", "Accounting", "Vice President", 47899);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`position = posi;`

and not

`posi = position;`

You're assigning here a null variable (`position`) to an immutable parameter (`posi`).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already stated that your mistake is

```
posi = position
```

Luiggi Mendoza also made a comment stating that you should use "this"!

I just want to give you a complete example on how it should be done.

```
public class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int idNumber;
    private String department;
    private String position;

    public Employee(String name, String department, String position, int idNumber)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.department = department;
       this.position = position;
       this.idNumber = idNumber;    
    }
}
```

Accessing your class variables explicit by this also spares you the hassle of making up new variable names like "nam" and "pos".

Answer (score 0):

For your constructor argument `posi`, you want to take that value and assign it to one of the class fields which in this example would be `position`. Now, what you're doing is assigning `position` (which is null) to `posi`. So you're overwriting your argument with null and not really doing anything with it.

What you want to do is the following:

```
position = posi;
```

which assigns the constructor argument i.e. `"Vice President` to the class field `position`.

Remember the variable on the right is assigned to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you of this statement:

```
posi = position;
```

Change it to

```
position =posi;
```

Use "this" pointer to avoid these errors. Happy Coding !!